# Pandas DataFrame: .replace() and .strip() methods returning NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I read a pdf file into a DataFrame using `tabula` and used **`.concat()`** to combine it all into one DataFrame by doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import tabula

df = tabula.read_pdf('card_details.pdf', pages='all')
df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```

I want to clean some of this data as a column which contains card numbers also has some non-numeric characters (question marks) in it. I've tried using `.replace()` and `.strip()` to remove these in a DataFrame that I made myself and it worked.

```
df['card_number'] = df['card_number'].str.strip('?')
```

or

```
df['card_number'] = df['card_number'].str.replace(r'\D+', '')
```

However, when I use it on this specific DataFrame that I read from the pdf, it returns NaN values for most of the data. Here's some screenshots of the DataFrame before and after.

[image: DataFrame before cleaning]

[image: DataFrame after cleaning]

Out of 15309 rows, only 2400 are not **NaN** - there are only around 50 rows that contain non-numeric values in them. So I really don't understand what's happening here as the card numbers without non-numeric characters are becoming null. Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: did you just post an image of credit card numbers?

Comment: They're not real, it's a fake dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when there is actual numerical data in the table. You can cast all the data to string first:

```
df['card_number'] = df['card_number'].astype(str).str.replace(r'\D+', '')
```